# Regular expression to context free grammar

Tags: computation-theory

Does this CFG look right? I am building a CFG for this RE:
(a U b)* U ab(a U b)*

```
    this is the CFG:
    s1->a
    s2->b
```

this is for the first (a U b)*

```
 s3->s1|s2        (a U b)
    s4->s3s4|E       (a U b)*
```

this is for the ab in the middle

```
s5->a
s6->b
```

this is for the second (a U b) and (ab) in the middle

```
   s7->s1|s2         (a U b) 
    s8->s7s8|E        (a U b)* 
    s9->s5s6          (ab)
```

concatenated ab with the second (a U b)*

```
  s10->s8s9         (ab(a U b)*)
```

this the final cfg

```
s11->s4|s10       (a U b)* U ab(a U b)*
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole thing looks correct except this:

```
s10->s8s9         (ab(a U b)*)
```

A moment's reflection should convince you that the correct production is

```
s10->s9s8
```